# How do you set configure.ac (autoconf) in my own application to auto-discover LAPACK, ATLAS, OpenBLAS, and KMP?

Tags: makefile, configure, autoconf, lapack, openblas

I'm new to autoconf as well as linear algebra libraries.  So far as I can tell,  LAPACK, ATLAS, OpenBLAS, and KML can co-exist on the filesystem but  you can only use one of the libraries at link-time and I would like to let ./configure choose whatever is available or let the user select it with ./configure --something.

Different distributions put things in different directories and it would be nice if autoconf can figure that out.

- LAPACK is -llapack
- ATLAS is -lsatlas -L /usr/lib64/atlas # CentOS

  - or -ltatlas for the threaded version
- OpenBLAS is -lopenblas

  - or -lopenblasp for the pthread version
  - or -lopenblaso for the OpenMP version

Questions:

- Is there already a "proper" way to do this with AC_ macros?

  - Do AC_ macros already exist for these libraries?
- How would you setup configure.ac to find the first available library that is installed but default to threaded ATLAS if available?
- How would you setup configure.ac to allow the user to select, for example, the OpenMP version of OpenBLAS?

  - Would you use an option like --with-openblas-openmp ?
  - What would the configure.ac code look like?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PSFEX package does this, see https://github.com/astromatic/psfex/blob/master/configure.ac#L285 :

```
# Provide special options for INTEL MKL and force the use of icc
AC_MSG_CHECKING([whether INTEL's MKL is enabled])
AC_ARG_ENABLE(mkl,
    [AS_HELP_STRING([--enable-mkl],
    [Use INTEL's MKL for solvers and FFTs (default = no)])],
        enable_icc="yes"
        CC="icc"
    AC_MSG_RESULT([yes]),
    AC_MSG_RESULT([no]))
    
# Provide special options for ATLAS
AC_ARG_WITH(atlas-libdir,
    [AS_HELP_STRING([--with-atlas-libdir=<ATLAS library path>],
    [Provide an alternative path to the ATLAS library])])
AC_ARG_WITH(atlas-incdir,
    [AS_HELP_STRING([--with-atlas-incdir=<ATLAS header dir>],
    [Provide an alternative path to the ATLAS header directory])])
    
# Provide special options for OpenBLAS
AC_MSG_CHECKING([whether OpenBLAS is enabled])
AC_ARG_ENABLE(openblas,
    [AS_HELP_STRING([--enable-openblas],
    [Use the OpenBLAS library instead of ATLAS (default = no)])],
    AC_MSG_RESULT([yes]),
    AC_MSG_RESULT([no]))
AC_ARG_WITH(openblas-libdir,
    [AS_HELP_STRING([--with-openblas-libdir=<OpenBLAS library path>],
    [Provide an alternative path to the OpenBLAS library])])
AC_ARG_WITH(openblas-incdir,
    [AS_HELP_STRING([--with-openblas-incdir=<OpenBLAS header dir>],
    [Provide an alternative path to the OpenBLAS header directory])])


############ handle the INTEL MKL library (FFTW + LAPACKe) ###########
if test "$enable_mkl" = "yes"; then
  convlibs="${srcdir}/../src/wcs/libwcs_c.a,${srcdir}/../src/levmar/liblevmar.a"
  ACX_MKL($with_mkl_dir,no,$enable_best_link,$convlibs)
  AC_MSG_CHECKING([for the INTEL MKL])
  if test "$MKL_WARN" == ""; then
    AC_MSG_RESULT([yes])
  else
    AC_MSG_RESULT([no])
    AC_MSG_WARN([$MKL_WARN])
  fi
  AM_CFLAGS="$AM_CFLAGS $MKL_CFLAGS "
  AM_LDFLAGS="$AM_LDFLAGS $MKL_LDFLAGS "
  LIBS="$LIBS $MKL_LIBS"

############ Select either openblas or atlas ############
else    
  if test "x$enable_openblas" = "xyes"; then
    ######## Handle the OpenBLAS library (linear algebra: BLAS + LAPACKe) ########
    ACX_OPENBLAS($with_openblas_libdir, $with_openblas_incdir, $use_pthreads, no,
      [
        AM_CFLAGS="$AM_CFLAGS $OPENBLAS_CFLAGS "
        AM_LDFLAGS="$AM_LDFLAGS $OPENBLAS_LDFLAGS "
        LIBS="$OPENBLAS_LIBS $LIBS"
        if test "$OPENBLAS_WARN" != ""; then
          AC_MSG_WARN([$OPENBLAS_WARN])
        fi
      ],
      AC_MSG_ERROR([$OPENBLAS_ERROR Exiting.])
    )

  else
    ######### handle the ATLAS library (linear algebra: BLAS + cLAPACK) ##########
    ACX_ATLAS($with_atlas_libdir, $with_atlas_incdir, $use_pthreads,
      [
        [LIBS="$ATLAS_LIBS $LIBS"]
        if test "$ATLAS_WARN" != ""; then
      AC_MSG_WARN([$ATLAS_WARN])
    fi
      ],
      AC_MSG_ERROR([$ATLAS_ERROR Exiting. You could try --enable-openblas if Atlas is unavailable.])
    )
  fi
fi

AC_ARG_WITH([lapack],
  [AS_HELP_STRING([--without-lapack],
  [disable support for lapack])],
  [],
  [with_lapack=no])

LIBLAPACK=
  AS_IF([test "x$with_lapack" != xno],
  [
    AX_BLAS([], [AC_MSG_ERROR([BLAS library not found])])
    AX_LAPACK([], [AC_MSG_ERROR([LAPACK library not found])])

    LIBS="$LAPACK_LIBS $BLAS_LIBS $LIBS $FLIBS"
    AC_CHECK_LIB(
    [lapack], [zgetrf], 
    [AC_SUBST([LIBLAPACK], ["$LAPACK_LIBS $BLAS_LIBS $LIBS $FLIBS"]) AC_DEFINE([LAPACK], [1], [Define if you have liblapack])],
    [AC_MSG_FAILURE([lapack library test failed (--without-lapack to disable)])],
    [])
  ])
```

Also note that you will need their macro libraries ([available here](https://github.com/astromatic/psfex/tree/master/m4)) which are too big to paste into the answer:

- acx_mkl.m4
- acx_atlas.m4
- acx_openblas.m4

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dlopen()` to dynamically load the library functions that you need.  Then you needn't worry about configure.ac settings since your application would auto-detect the available libraries at runtime.

The [xnec2c antenna simulator](https://www.xnec2c.org/) does this using their [mathlib.c](https://github.com/KJ7LNW/xnec2c/blob/ee25177ae8718b1e0ff6149b77e2938387e2614c/src/mathlib.c) and [mathlib.h](https://github.com/KJ7LNW/xnec2c/blob/c1db6d553ccee9e6a421b7cf20417bec6d1c33b9/src/mathlib.h) implementations for the `zgetrf()` and `zgetrs()` calls.  It could be extended to support other linear algebra calls as well.  Maybe someone will write a unified linear algebra meta-library to dynamically back all the various implementations in one front-end library!  (If you do, be sure to tell the xnec2c maintainer so they might use your changes.)

The [mathlib.c](https://github.com/KJ7LNW/xnec2c/blob/ee25177ae8718b1e0ff6149b77e2938387e2614c/src/mathlib.c) file contains a typedef struct `mathlib_t` that defines the library names, shared object path, and function prefix for each library.  It supports shared object library names for autodetecting Ubuntu/Debian, CentOS/RHEL, and openSUSE at runtime; other distributions more-or-less use the same library names, so, effectively, far more than just the above listed distributions are supported:

```c
static mathlib_t mathlibs[] = {
    {.type = MATHLIB_ATLAS, .lib = "libtatlas.so.3", .name = "ATLAS, Threaded", .f_prefix = "clapack_"},
    {.type = MATHLIB_OPENBLAS, .lib = "libopenblaso.so", .name = "OpenBLAS+LAPACKe, OpenMP", .f_prefix = "LAPACKE_"},
}
```

Note that ATLAS and OpenBLAS use different function prefixes: `clapack_` vs `LAPACKE_`; so having a wrapper around the different libraries is useful.  Xnec2c supports ATLAS, OpenBLAS+LAPACK, and Intel MKL.